# Automatic reload of "database" beans, possible?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

Is there somehow possible to create a number of beans holding database data, and when the database is updated the necessary beans (not the entire context!) are automatically updated?

The background is that I recently migrated an old web application to the Spring Framework and Hibernate. Before the migration, when a database table was updated a pre-defined set of singletons where updated. I haven't found a nice and simple solution for this in Spring yet.

/Bagerth

Context:

```
<beans:bean id="systems" class="." factory-method="createInstance">  
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="customers"/>  
</beans:bean>
```

Bean:

```
public class Systems {
    public static ArrayList<System> createInstance(ArrayList<Customer> customers) {
        ArrayList<System> systems = new ArrayList<System>();
        // code to populate systems ...
        return systems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance that approach maybe used:

Note that reload methods are pre-defined methods which do the reload work on its singleton.

```
@Component
public class MyReloader {

    @Autowired
    AService aService;

    @Autowired
    BService bService;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2 * 1000)
    public void reload() {
        aService.reload();
        bService.reload();
    }

}
```

Another approach (async) you implement an [ApplicationListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) and trigger a custom event that forces singlentons reload themselves.

Comment: Could you please give an example on how to build up a reload method?
I haven't been able to figure out how to update a single bean without reloading/refreshing the entire context.